# Toggle switch that copies input once the switch is turned on

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When I put in the time for the Monday From and Monday To inputs in the code below I have a switch that I want to copy the times I put in for Monday From/To for the rest of the week. How do I do that? This is a vue file using typescript so I'm assuming this will have to be written in typescript. Here is the code in the vue file for the inputs and toggle switch. This can also be a button too if that is easier. I'm only showing code for Monday and Tuesday inputs instead of the entire week.

```html
<b-row class="pb-0">
  <b-col lg="6">
    <!-- <strong>Monday</strong> -->
    <common-forminputs-btextinputwithvalidation
      id="providerMondayOpen"
      v-model="providerScheduleDays.mondayOpenHour"
      :rules="`compare_to_end_time:${providerScheduleDays.mondayCloseHour}`"
      label="Monday From"
      required-display-name="From"
      name="providerMondayOpen"
      label-class="w-50 pl-2"
      input-class="mb-2"
      type="time"
    />
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="6">
    <common-forminputs-btextinputwithvalidation
      id="providerMondayClose"
      v-model="providerScheduleDays.mondayCloseHour"
      :rules="`compare_to_start_time:${providerScheduleDays.mondayOpenHour}`"
      label="Monday To"
      required-display-name="To"
      name="providerMondayClose"
      label-class="w-50 pl-2"
      input-class="mb-2"
      type="time"
    />
  </b-col>
</b-row>
<b-row class="pb-0">
  <b-col lg="6">
    <!-- <strong>Tuesday</strong> -->
    <common-forminputs-btextinputwithvalidation
      id="providerTuesdayOpen"
      v-model="providerScheduleDays.tuesdayOpenHour"
      :rules="`compare_to_end_time:${providerScheduleDays.tuesdayCloseHour}`"
      label="Tuesday From"
      required-display-name="From"
      name="providerTuesdayOpen"
      label-class="w-50 pl-2"
      input-class="mb-2"
      type="time"
    />
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="6">
    <!-- <strong>Tuesday</strong> -->
    <common-forminputs-btextinputwithvalidation
      id="providerTuesdayClose"
      v-model="providerScheduleDays.tuesdayCloseHour"
      :rules="`compare_to_start_time:${providerScheduleDays.tuesdayOpenHour}`"
      label="Tuesday To"
      required-display-name="To"
      name="providerTuesdayClose"
      label-class="w-50 pl-2"
      input-class="mb-2"
      type="time"
    />
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Copy switch toggle

```html
<b-row class="pb-0">
  <b-col>
    <b-form-checkbox switch v- model="providerScheduleDays.isCopytoMF">
      Copy times to Mon-Fri
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Here is the object code

```
async getProviderScheduleDays() { //this is for loading saved database data
    const providerId = this.providerId ?? 0;
    if (providerId > 0) {            
        await this.providerApplicationClient.getProviderScheduleDays(
            providerId //local variable from routes
        ).catch((e) => {
            window.console.log("Provider Schedule issue"); //code review 
        }).then((providerScheduleDays) =>{
            if (providerScheduleDays){  //checks if not null, void, or undefined
        //     window.console.log(providerScheduleDays);
              
               this.providerScheduleDays = providerScheduleDays;
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, you want to have a backup of all your `providerScheduleDays.{day}{openOrClose}Hour` copied to another object ? How does the `providerScheduleDays` object look like ? Are you sure that you want to have it nested in `providerScheduleDays` ?

Comment: When I type in something for Monday from and to inputs like 9PM to 11PM, when I click the providerScheduleDays.isCopytoMF switch to on I want it to copy 9PM-11PM for Tuesday thru Friday. I only provided Mon and Tues could above because it would have been more code. I don't know exactly what you mean by how does the providerScheduleDays object look like. I posted some more code in the OP.

Comment: Any help on this @kissu or did you just kind of give up?